# How should I improve the performance of this C++ code?

Tags: c++, optimization, x86, sse, simd

The following code operates on two `std::vectors` `v1` and `v2`, each containing multiple 128-element vectors. Loops through the outer vectors (using `i1` and `i2`) contain an inner loop, designed to limit the combinations of `i1` and `i2` for which further complex processing is performed. Around 99.9% of the combinations are filtered out.

Unfortunately the filtering loop is a major bottleneck in my program - profiling shows that 26% of the entire run time is spent on the line `if(a[k] + b[k] > LIMIT)`.

```
const vector<vector<uint16_t>> & v1 = ...
const vector<vector<uint16_t>> & v2 = ...

for(size_t i1 = 0; i1 < v1.size(); ++i1) { //v1.size() and v2.size() about 20000
    for(size_t i2 = 0; i2 < v2.size(); ++i2) {

        const vector<uint16_t> & a = v1[i1];
        const vector<uint16_t> & b = v2[i2];

        bool good = true;
        for(std::size_t k = 0; k < 128; ++k) {
            if(a[k] + b[k] > LIMIT) { //LIMIT is a const uint16_t: approx 16000
                good = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!good) continue;

        // Further processing involving i1 and i2
    }
}
```

I think the performance of this code could be improved by increasing memory locality, plus perhaps vectorizing. Any suggestions on how to do this, or on other improvements that could be made?

Comment: Should probably go to codereview instead (they should put that already into the list of offtopic close votes)

Comment: sounds like branch prediction problem. sse would solve it

Comment: Can the data structure be simplified?

Comment: micro optimization: use goto instead of the good/continue. depending on your data you could sort the vectors, or rule out a complete i1/i2 when single elements themselves are > 128.#

Comment: @BЈовић - Are you able to sketch out for me a solution using SSE?

Comment: @MichaelD - I am free to change the data structure in any way. Until now I have used vector<vector<X>> for convenience.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately sorting `a` and `b` will not give the correct result: `good` should only be set to `false` if `a[k]+b[k]>LIMIT`, not if `a[k]+b[l]>LIMIT` for `l` != `k`. Also, a previous step has already ruled out i1/i2 if a single element is > 128.

Comment: If the inner vectors are always of `size = 128`, use `std::array`, one less indirection to reach the elements.

Comment: I concur to what @DanielKO suggests; plus, why are you not using iterators, instead of indexes? I guess it could bring some speedup too. But still, this all gives number of operations in the order of 20000x20000x128. This is a huge number, any chance of rethinking the overall idea?

Comment: +1 for having profiled first.

Comment: Did you mean 'a previous step has already ruled out i1/i2 if a single element is > LIMIT' (rather than > 128)? I was going to suggest that.

Comment: Do you know a[k] + b[k] will always be less than 65536? Otherwise your code testing against LIMIT has a potential integer overflow bug.

Answer (score 3):

You could apply SIMD to the inner loop:

```
    bool good = true;
    for(std::size_t k = 0; k < 128; ++k) {
        if(a[k] + b[k] > LIMIT) { //LIMIT is a const uint16_t: approx 16000
            good = false;
            break;
        }
```

as follows:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>  // SSE2 intrinsics
#include <limits.h>     // SHRT_MIN

// ...

    // some useful constants - declare these somewhere before the outermost loop

    const __m128i vLIMIT = _mm_set1_epi16(LIMIT + SHRT_MIN); // signed version of LIMIT
    const __m128i vOFFSET = _mm_set1_epi16(SHRT_MIN);        // offset for uint16_t -> int16_t conversion

// ...

    bool good = true;
    for(std::size_t k = 0; k < 128; k += 8) {
        __m128i v, va, vb;              // iterate through a, b, 8 elements at a time
        int mask;
        va = _mm_loadu_si128(&a[k]);    // get 8 elements from a[k], b[k]
        vb = _mm_loadu_si128(&b[k]);
        v = _mm_add_epi16(va, vb);      // add a and b vectors
        v = _mm_add_epi16(v, vOFFSET);  // subtract 32768 to make signed
        v = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(v, vLIMIT); // compare against LIMIT
        mask = _mm_maskmove_epi8(v);    // get comparison results as 16 bit mask
        if (mask != 0) {                // if any value exceeded limit
            good = false;               // clear good flag and exit loop
            break;
        }
```

Warning: untested code - may need debugging, but the general approach should be sound.

Comment: @BЈовић: yes, unfortunately you don't have much control over the alignment of a std::vector. Fortunately though misaligned loads are not too expensive on modern CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the most efficient access pattern for `v1`, but you are sequentially scanning through all of `v2` for each iteration of the outer loop.  This is very inefficient, because `v2` access will continually cause (L2 and probably also L3) cache misses.

A better access pattern is to increase the loop nesting, so that outer loops stride through `v1` and `v2`, and inner loops process elements within a subsegment of both `v1` and `v2` that's small enough to fit in cache.

Basically, instead of

```
for(size_t i1 = 0; i1 < v1.size(); ++i1) { //v1.size() and v2.size() about 20000
    for(size_t i2 = 0; i2 < v2.size(); ++i2) {
```

Do

```
for(size_t i2a = 0; i2a < v2.size(); i2a += 32) {
    for(size_t i1 = 0; i1 < v1.size(); ++i1) {
        for(size_t i2 = i2a; i2 < v2.size() && i2 < i2a + 32; ++i2) {
```

Or

```
size_t i2a = 0;

// handle complete blocks
for(; i2a < v2.size() - 31; i2a += 32) {
    for(size_t i1 = 0; i1 < v1.size(); ++i1) {
        for(size_t i2 = i2a; i2 < i2a + 32; ++i2) {

        }
    }
}

// handle leftover partial block
for(size_t i1 = 0; i1 < v1.size(); ++i1) {
    for(size_t i2 = i2a; i2 < v2.size(); ++i2) {
    }
}
```

This way, a chunk of `32 * 128 * sizeof (uint16_t)` bytes, or 8kB, will be loaded from `v2` into cache, and then reused 20,000 times.

This improvement is orthogonal to SIMD (SSE) vectorization.  It will interact with thread-based parallelism, but probably in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

First, One simple optimization can be this, but the compiler could do this by itself so i'm not sure how much it could improve:

```
for(std::size_t k = 0; k < 128 && good; ++k)
{
    good = a[k] + b[k] <= LIMIT;
}
```

Second, i think it could better to keep the good result in a second vector because any 
processing involved with i1 and i2 could break the CPU cache.

Third, and this could be major optimization, i think you can rewrite the second for loop as this:
for(size_t i2 = i1; i2 < v2.size(); ++i2) since you are using + operations for a and b vectors which is commutative so the result of i1 and i2 will be the same as i2 and i1.
For this you need to have the v1 and v2 the same size. If the size is different you need to write the iteration in a different way.

Fort, As far as i can see you are processing two matrices, it would be better to keep a vector of elements rather than a vector of vectors.

Hope this helps.
Razvan.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- As suggested in the comments, replace the inner 128 element vector with an array for better memory locality.
- This code looks highly parallelizable, have you tried that? You could split the combinations for filtering across all available cores and then rebalance the collected work and split the processing across all cores.

I implemented a version using arrays for the inner 128 elements, PPL for parallelization (requires VS 2012 or higher) and a bit of SSE code for the filtering and got a pretty significant speedup. Depending on what exactly the 'further processing' involves there may be benefits to structuring things slightly differently (in this example I don't rebalance the work after filtering for example).

**Update:** I implemented the cache blocking suggested by Ben Voigt and got a bit more of a speed up.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
#include <iterator>

#include <ppl.h>

#include <immintrin.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace concurrency;

namespace {
const int outerVecSize = 20000;
const int innerVecSize = 128;
const int LIMIT = 16000;
auto engine = default_random_engine();
};

typedef vector<uint16_t> InnerVec;
typedef array<uint16_t, innerVecSize> InnerArr;

template <typename Cont> void randomFill(Cont& c) {
    // We want approx 0.1% to pass filter, the mean and standard deviation are chosen to get close to that
    static auto dist = normal_distribution<>(LIMIT / 4.0, LIMIT / 4.6);
    generate(begin(c), end(c), [] {
        auto clamp = [](double x, double minimum, double maximum) { return min(max(minimum, x), maximum); };
        return static_cast<uint16_t>(clamp(dist(engine), 0.0, numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()));
    });
}

void resizeInner(InnerVec& v) { v.resize(innerVecSize); }
void resizeInner(InnerArr& a) {}

template <typename Inner> Inner generateRandomInner() {
    auto inner = Inner();
    resizeInner(inner);
    randomFill(inner);
    return inner;
}

template <typename Inner> vector<Inner> generateRandomInput() {
    auto outer = vector<Inner>(outerVecSize);
    generate(begin(outer), end(outer), generateRandomInner<Inner>);
    return outer;
}

void Report(const chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration elapsed, size_t in1Size, size_t in2Size,
            const int passedFilter, const uint32_t specialValue) {
    cout << passedFilter << "/" << in1Size* in2Size << " ("
         << 100.0 * (double(passedFilter) / double(in1Size * in2Size)) << "%) passed filter\n";
    cout << specialValue << "\n";
    cout << "Elapsed time = " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed).count() << "ms" << endl;
}

void TestOriginalVersion() {
    cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;

    engine.seed();
    const auto v1 = generateRandomInput<InnerVec>();
    const auto v2 = generateRandomInput<InnerVec>();

    int passedFilter = 0;
    uint32_t specialValue = 0;

    auto startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (size_t i1 = 0; i1 < v1.size(); ++i1) { // v1.size() and v2.size() about 20000
        for (size_t i2 = 0; i2 < v2.size(); ++i2) {

            const vector<uint16_t>& a = v1[i1];
            const vector<uint16_t>& b = v2[i2];

            bool good = true;
            for (std::size_t k = 0; k < 128; ++k) {
                if (static_cast<int>(a[k]) + static_cast<int>(b[k])
                    > LIMIT) { // LIMIT is a const uint16_t: approx 16000
                    good = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!good) continue;

            // Further processing involving i1 and i2
            ++passedFilter;
            specialValue += inner_product(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), 0);
        }
    }

    auto endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    Report(endTime - startTime, v1.size(), v2.size(), passedFilter, specialValue);
}

bool needsProcessing(const InnerArr& a, const InnerArr& b) {
    static_assert(sizeof(a) == sizeof(b) && (sizeof(a) % 16) == 0, "Array size must be multiple of 16 bytes.");
    static const __m128i mmLimit = _mm_set1_epi16(LIMIT);
    static const __m128i mmLimitPlus1 = _mm_set1_epi16(LIMIT + 1);
    static const __m128i mmOnes = _mm_set1_epi16(-1);

    auto to_m128i = [](const uint16_t* p) { return reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(p); };
    return equal(to_m128i(a.data()), to_m128i(a.data() + a.size()), to_m128i(b.data()), [&](const __m128i& a, const __m128i& b) {
        // avoid overflow due to signed compare by clamping sum to LIMIT + 1
        const __m128i clampSum = _mm_min_epu16(_mm_adds_epu16(a, b), mmLimitPlus1);
        return _mm_test_all_zeros(_mm_cmpgt_epi16(clampSum, mmLimit), mmOnes);
    });
}

void TestArrayParallelVersion() {
    cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;

    engine.seed();
    const auto v1 = generateRandomInput<InnerArr>();
    const auto v2 = generateRandomInput<InnerArr>();

    combinable<int> passedFilterCombinable;
    combinable<uint32_t> specialValueCombinable;

    auto startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    const size_t blockSize = 64;

    parallel_for(0u, v1.size(), blockSize, [&](size_t i) {
        for (const auto& b : v2) {
            const auto blockBegin = begin(v1) + i;
            const auto blockEnd = begin(v1) + min(v1.size(), i + blockSize);
            for (auto it = blockBegin; it != blockEnd; ++it) {
                const InnerArr& a = *it;
                if (!needsProcessing(a, b))
                    continue;

                // Further processing involving a and b
                ++passedFilterCombinable.local();
                specialValueCombinable.local() += inner_product(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), 0);
            }
        }
    });

    auto passedFilter = passedFilterCombinable.combine(plus<int>());
    auto specialValue = specialValueCombinable.combine(plus<uint32_t>());

    auto endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    Report(endTime - startTime, v1.size(), v2.size(), passedFilter, specialValue);
}

int main() {
    TestOriginalVersion();
    TestArrayParallelVersion();
}
```

On my 8 core system I see a pretty good speedup, your results will vary depending on how many cores you have etc.

```
TestOriginalVersion
441579/400000000 (0.110395%) passed filter
2447300015
Elapsed time = 12525ms
TestArrayParallelVersion
441579/400000000 (0.110395%) passed filter
2447300015
Elapsed time = 657ms
```